# Edited page_footer the result not change

Tags: html, footer

This is the detail of what I want edit.

[image]

Here the content of `page_footer.tpl`

```
<div class="page_footer">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.mihalism.net/multihost/">Mihalism Multi Host</a> v<# VERSION #>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google_stats("UA-1125794-2");
</script>
```

Edited but the result not change. Suggestions?

Comment: If you are using smarty template engine. Try cleaning the cache folder.

Comment: Solved. I have wrong file. The right file was in another folder. :D